Upgraded version of MariaDB still dumps older version
EDIT: Found out what I was doing wrong. I was using mariadb-dump to import instead of just mariadb.
I upgraded from MariaDB 10.x to 11.x. mariadb -V is showing the updated version.
I exported the database (which was retained during upgrade) via MySQL/MariaDB-dump and got the infamous sandbox error.
Using sed or piping commands, we can get it uploaded, but it's annoying.
We ran mariadb-upgrade and it still had the same error.
/*M!999999\- enable the sandbox mode */
-- MariaDB dump 10.19-11.5.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database:
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       11.5.2-MariaDB-ubu2204

Logically, two things could be going on. One is that somehow the dump program is still the older version, possibly because it was never overwritten despite the rest being upgraded.
Second possibility is that the database itself is still the older version. Either because mariadb-upgrade was incorrect or maybe a new database has to be made under the current MariaDB.
I have not tried mariabackup yet, but that looks like a possible solution.
Question: How can I troubleshoot this, and any potential solutions?
EDIT: To clarify the import/export command I am using goes like this;

For export:
mariadb-dump -u username -p DBname > filename.sql
Import:
mariadb-dump -u username -p DBname < filename.sql
NOTE: I used both mariadb-dump and mysql dump (which just switched to
maria).

EDIT 2:
So I think the database is exporting fine. The issue is that my database may be corrupted. /M!999999\ is different than /!999999\ sandbox bug. Looks like an M was inserted.

The database dump appears to be taken via the the new version because /*M!99999.... If mariadb -V is showing the latest version, are you using this client in some way? And per below the server version is 11.5.2. How are you using the SQL Dump in such a way as to trigger the sandbox protection? What sort of "upload" are you doing?

What I did was try to restore backups on a test server with the same environment. I updated this question with the commands I used.
I see your point, it is inexplicable because both environments are running the same version of mariaDB and the sandbox iss only happens going to on older version of mariaDB, not a newer.

Ran this command to check the SQL file:
customer@host:/var/www$ head -n 5 db.sql :::OUTPUT::::
/*M!999999- enable the sandbox mode */
-- MariaDB dump 10.19-11.5.2-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)

So I think the database is exporting fine. The issue is that my database may be corrupted. /M!999999\ is different than /!999999. Looks like an M was inserted.

Yes, M was inserted last release to make this only parsed by MariaDB clients. This way mysql clients can interact (but technically are vulnerable).

did you try mariadb-dump -V?

@danblack interesting. But both the test and production server are now using the same version, not sure why it's throughing the sandbox error. ysth I will try that next backup, thanks.

@danblack found out what I was doing wrong. I was using mariadb-dump to import instead of just mariadb.

Found out what I was doing wrong. I was using mariadb-dump to import instead of just mariadb. I'm used to using mysql/mysqldump.
